# Ember.js - Get Result

Tags: ember.js

I am a beginner in Ember.js and I would like to get a response result and show in my view (HTML).

My Result:

```
{"teste": { "code": "1", "message": "hello" } }
```

My controller in Ember.js:

```
actions: {
  discountCoupon: function() {
    var lista =  _this.store.find('teste', { "param": "123" });
    console.info("return=" + lista.get('code'));
    // result return===undefined
    console.info("return===" + lista.get('message'));
    // result return===undefined
  },
  ...
}
```

My model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  code: DS.attr('string'),
  message: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

I can't get the return of my backend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use a promise....

Comment: What version of Ember Data are you using? `store.find` is a private method in 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more thing, because you're using Ember Data and try to search using `store.find('model', { queryParams })` Ember expects the backend to return a result in plural:
`{"testes": [{"code":"1","message":"hello"}}]`

Answer (score 2):

first you need to go and find what ever you are looking for, then you    get your results. Remember When javascript `promise` you something will always give you a result back back....

```
actions: {

discountCoupon: function(){
   var listas =  _this.store.find('testes', { 
        param: "123" 
   }).then(function(lista){

       console.log("return=" + lista.get('code'));
       console.log("return===" + lista.get('message'));
    });
},
```